# Parsing and storing the values of a csv file using shell script outputs :::: instead of actual characters

Tags: bash, shell, csv, scripting

I am trying to read a csv file using shell script,using the following command.

```
cat file.csv | while read -r a b c d e f; do echo "$a:$b:$c:$d:$e:$f"; done
```

When i run this command the first column in the file is not being read properly.

For Ex: If 1 st column contents are

```
number1,
number2,
number3,
number4,
(so on)
```

It outputs:

```
::::er1,
::::er2,
::::er3,
::::er4,
```

some characters are replaced by ':' 
this happens only for the first column contents. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: It looks to me like you have DOS-style CRLF line endings on a Unix machine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Wasn't the not setting of `IFS` causing the issue here?

Comment: That too, but the colons at the start of the line indicate to me that there is a CR that's been kept as part of the data (because Unix lines end at the LF; the CR is just a character on the line).  So, yes — IFS is probably part of the trouble, but the data probably comes from Windows, or travelled via a Windows machine at some point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to most likely a couple of issues:-

- You are reading the file without the `IFS=,`
- Your `csv` file might likely have carriage returns(`\r`) which could mangle how `read` command processes the input stream.

To remove the carriage returns(`\r`) use `tr -d '\r' < oldFile.csv > newFile.csv` and in the new file do the parsing as mentioned below.

Without setting the Internal Field Separator (`IFS=","`), while reading from the input stream `read` doesn't know where to delimit your words. Add the same in the command as below.

```
cat file.csv | while IFS="," read -r a b c d e f; do echo "$a:$b:$c:$d:$e:$f"; done
```

You can see it working as below. I have the contents of the `file.csv` as follows.

```
$ cat file.csv
abc,def,ghi,ijk,lmn,opz
1,2,3,4,5,6

$ cat file.csv | while IFS="," read -r a b c d e f; do echo "$a:$b:$c:$d:$e:$f"; done
abc:def:ghi:ijk:lmn:opz
1:2:3:4:5:6
```

More over using `cat` and looping it over it is not recommended and bash enthusiasts often call it as [`UUOC - Useless Use Of Cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

You can avoid this by doing

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS="," read -r a b c d e f;
do
    echo "$a:$b:$c:$d:$e:$f"
done < file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much @inian for the detailed explanation, by including IFS=',' solved my issue.

Comment: i upvoted it, but it is not publicly visible cos i still don't have the minimum reputations.